# Import tar file into private docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-push

We have built .tar file from docker images using `docker save` command and packaged all .tar file into .tgz file, then we copy. tgz file to air-gapped system where we have set up the private docker registry. Now we want to push .tar file from .tgz into private docker registry. 
One way is to do `docker load` then `docker push` but the total time to do this task is much on the higher side. Is there any other way to achieve the same without loading .tar into docker daemon first?

Answer (score 2):

this command may help you in this case:

install this package

**pip install dockertarpusher**

then follow this command to your concern,

**docker-tar-push {REGISTRYURL} {TARPATH} [login] [password] [--noSslVerify]**

Refer this link :
https://pypi.org/project/dockertarpusher/0.16/

Comment: I already looked into this package and I guess this is kind of wrapper over the `docker load` and `docker push`. Have you used this package?

Comment: I always used the load and push methods only. But searched for your solution i will notify once i got tried with this